# Call a php function in MVC using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am currently migrating an already built web application to MVC, and I'm figuring out that I'm too newbie to do some kind of changes.  There are some ajax calls that are freaking me out.  I'll try to be as clear as possible, but due to my inexperience I'm not sure if I won't let some important information by the way.

The point is in the old application, things go this way:

In the php code:

```
    if ($action_user == 'show_alerts') {
        $list = array();
        $query = "SELECT alert_type FROM alert_contact WHERE NOT 
        deleted AND user_email=" . typeFormat($email);
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error in query "'.$query . '": ' . mysqli_error($db));
        while ($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $list[] = $db_field['alert_type'];
        }
        echo json_encode($list);
```

In the jquery code:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'userpost.php',
            data: $('#userForm').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json'
```

Here comes my problem, and since I don't have an userpost.php file anymore, I have to send it to the index.php and call my users component by a get petition, which I don't like, but I coudn't find another way to do it. And, what is even worse, I don't know at all how ajax is getting the variables that it needs.  It must be a pretty basic mistake, but I recognize my skills at this point are't so good. That's what I'm doing in my version:

In the php code:

```
    if ($action_user == 'show_alerts') {
            $list = ModelUser::getAlertContact($act_email);
            echo json_encode($list);//I predict that ajax don't reach this line, but not sure
    }
```

In the jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?option=users',
        data: $('#userForm').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert ('gotcha');
        $.each(alertsarray, function(index, value) {
            if ($.inArray(value, data) === -1) {
                $("#sub" + value).prop("checked", false);
                $('#alert' + value).removeClass("list_alert_sub");
            }
            else {
                $("#sub" + value).prop("checked", true);
                $('#alert' + value).addClass("list_alert_sub");
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("¡Error (ajax)!");
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, and if there's some more information I've missed, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I've been making some progress but don't seem to find a real solution.  Now I know that the url has to be the controller, so I'm using 'components/userpost/controller.php' as it, and it reaches the ajax call, cause the success alert is showing up. The problem is the MVC way, because I send ajax to the controller, but since I don't have a reload in the page, all the includes are failing so they are obviously not being loaded, and I'm getting errors like this:

> PHP Warning:  include(components/userpost/model.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/viewer_mvc/components/userpost/controller.php on line 3,
>   referer: http://localhost/viewer_mvc/index.php

Really hope you guys can show me where am I failing, and if there's a special way to do these thing in MVC.

Comment: might help to mention what framework you are using and tag question with it also

Comment: I'm not using any framework.  All I have is a file with a function _loader($component)_ that returns the route to the controller of the component I want to load.  I don't know what is a tag question, could you please tell me what it is for? Maybe is what I'm missing here? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the JQuery call it makes a POST request to `index.php?option=users` with JSON data. The form with the ID `userForm` is serialized using the Jquery `serialize` method.

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?option=users',
    data: $('#userForm').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json'
```

Now for your PHP sample

```
if ($action_user == 'show_alerts') {
    $list = ModelUser::getAlertContact($act_email);
    echo json_encode($list);//I predict that ajax don't reach this line, but not sure
}
```

This code will be looking for variables that probably don't exist anymore if it is a different file i.e. is there an `$action_user` variable?

To start reimplementing it you will need to add the logic so that it checks the POST variable if your not using the framework code. So if you have a form element with the name 'name' then that will be available in your PHP script POST variable

```
$_POST['name']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes, right above this _if($action_user == 'show_alerts')_ I check the POST variable, so that the variable is in this controller.  Anyway, as far as I understand, the variables that were at _userpost.php_ before now are at users/controller.php, to where I'm sending my ajax call, so things didn't change pretty much. What I really don't know is why the _$list_ array is not being passed.

Comment: Your not passing `$list` in the Ajax call. It passes the HTML form data

Comment: So when I do this _echo json_encode($list)_ I'm not passing the array? How can I do it?

Comment: @blinking_eyes you need a `done` callback in `$.ajax` to accept the json

Comment: @charlietfl I've just edited my jquery code with the whole function, it was unclear, sorry.  I'd like to ask you if having `success` it's the same of having `done`? Or I still need having `done` here?

Comment: @blinking_eyes yes, the docs however are deprecating `success` in favor of `done`. I am still guilty myself out of old habits of still using it myself

Comment: And currently I'm trying the `url: components/users/controller.php` which seems to be the correct one, and even though I get the correct variables when I verify the _httpResponse_ headers, I always get the error alert.

Comment: @charlietfl so I'll try with `done`, thanks a million for this info.

Comment: @blinking_eyes inspect the actual request in network tab of browser dev tools and make sure response body is valid json with nothing printed outside of the json

Answer (score -1):

[How to call a PHP function in MVC using AJAX]

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'save-user.php',
        data: { fname: "manish", email: "manishkp@com",  role:"admin"},
        success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    if(data == 'error')
    {
     $('#Register_error').text('Must Be filled...');
     $('#Register_error').show();
    }
   else {      
                                        $('#Register_error').hide();
     $('#Register_success').text('Successfully submit');
     $('#Register_success').show();
    }
  }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<?php 
   
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $role = $_POST['role'];
  
  if(!empty($fname) && !empty($email) && !empty($role))
  {
                      #MYSQL CONNECTION QUERY #
                       echo"success";
                }
                 else{
                         echo "error"; 
                }
?>
```